# html5 mobile webapp add to homescreen issue

Tags: javascript, mobile, web-applications

I have a webapp and it looks good when assigned to a users homescreen (ios) but not as good when just going to it from safari.  Is there a way to control which scripts/items run when the webapp is accessed from safari only?  And then a sepperate script/code to run when launched from the homescreen?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the web page is set up to use no address bar etc, when launched from home screen link. And you want to detect when it's not launched that way (to correct for smaller vertical space etc.)

Then what you want to detect is "app mode" or "standalone mode". [This site seems to explain quite well how to detect it](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm).

(In case this link dies in the future) in essence the test is

```
if ( ("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone ){
  // Not standalone/fullscreen here (visiting from safari)
}else{
  //Fullscreen mode (launched from homescreen)
}
```